# Making a function in terms of a sum from 1 to n in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, sum, equation

I'm trying to get Matlab to take this as a function of `x_1` through `x_n` and `y_1` through `y_n`, where `k_i` and `r_i` are all constants.

[image: $$ \sum_{i=2}^{n} ( k_{i-1}*( \sqrt ( (x_i - x_{i-1})^2 + (y_{i}-y_{i-1})^2 ) -r_{i-1})^2$$]

So far my idea was to take `n` from the user and make two 1×n vectors called `x` and `y`, and for the `x_i` just pull out `x(i)`. But I don't know how to make an arbitrary sum in MATLAB.

I also need to get the gradient of this function, which I don't know how to do either. I was thinking maybe I could make a loop and add that to the function each time, but MATLAB doesn't like that.

Comment: It's hard for me to read your formatting (LaTeX doesn't work on StackOverflow), but if you don't depend on previous results in the sum, you shouldn't need a loop. Just calculate the value for each index in a big vector, and then sum up the whole vector.

Comment: Sorry, yeah... I didn't know LaTeX wouldn't work. That seems like a good idea but probably has the same problem I said in my reply below

Comment: Well, if you try to say something like: `x = []; x(10) = 1;`, then MATLAB will indeed fill the missing values with zeros. But you have a larger fundamental problem: you don't seem to have all of the values you need for `x` and `y`. In that case, you need to have a think about how to get those values. You may be able to calculate them in your loop? But in order for your result to be meaningful you'll need to get those values.

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis: MATLAB can typeset LaTeX for you. See my edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe a loop is necessary for this calculation. MATLAB excels at vectorized operations, so would something like this work for you?

```
l = 10; % how large these vectors are
k = rand(l,1); % random junk values to work with
r = rand(l,1);
x = rand(l,1);
y = rand(l,1);
vals = k(1:end-1) .* (sqrt(diff(x).^2 + diff(y).^2) - r(1:end-1)).^2;
sum(vals)
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Amro for correcting the formula and simplifying it with `diff`.

Comment: actually your formula is a bit off: `k(1:end-1) .* (sqrt(diff(x).^2 + diff(y).^2) - r(1:end-1)).^2` (check the LaTeX source to get the right parentheses order)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for the gradient symbolically with:

```
n = 10;
k = sym('k',[1 n]); % Create n variables k1, k2, ..., kn
x = sym('x',[1 n]); % Create n variables x1, x2, ..., xn
y = sym('y',[1 n]); % Create n variables y1, y2, ..., yn
r = sym('r',[1 n]); % Create n variables r1, r2, ..., rn
% Symbolically sum equation
s = sum((k(1:end-1).*sqrt((x(2:end)-x(1:end-1)).^2+(y(2:end)-y(1:end-1)).^2)-r(1:end-1)).^2)
grad_x = gradient(s,x) % Gradient with respect to x vector
grad_y = gradient(s,y) % Gradient with respect to y vector
```

The symbolic sum and gradients can be evaluated and converted to floating point with:

```
% n random data values for k, x, y, and r
K = rand(1,n);
X = rand(1,n);
Y = rand(1,n);
R = rand(1,n);
% Substitute in data for symbolic variables
S = double(subs(s,{[k,x,y,r]},{[K,X,Y,R]}))
GRAD_X = double(subs(grad_x,{[k,x,y,r]},{[K,X,Y,R]}))
GRAD_Y = double(subs(grad_y,{[k,x,y,r]},{[K,X,Y,R]}))
```

The [`gradient`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html) function is the one overloaded for symbolic variables (type `help sym/gradient`) or see the [more detailed documentation online](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could indeed do this with a loop, considering that `x`, `y`, `k`, and `r` are already defined.

```
n = length(x);
s = 0;
for j = 2 : n
    s = s + k(j-1) * (sqrt((x(j) - x(j-1)).^2 + (y(j) - y(j-1)).^2) - r(j-1)).^2
end
```

You should derive the gradient analytically and then plug in numbers. It should not be too hard to expand these terms and then find derivatives of the resulting polynomial.

Comment: The thing is, x and y aren't already defined - I need them to be variables. And if I just write the function like this (thanks by the way, it works otherwise), for some reason matlab assigns the value 0 to all the x(j)s that it doesn't know. How do I stop that?

Comment: I need to pre-define x(1) and x(n), since they are actually constants in my function (all the other ones aren't). I didn't think that was important but maybe it's the reason Matlab thinks everything in between is a bunch of zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Vectorized solution is something like (I wonder why do you use sqrt().^2):

```
is = 2:n;
result = sum( k(is - 1) .* abs((x(is) - x(is-1)).^2 + (y(is) - y(is-1)).^2 - r(is-1)));
```

You can either compute gradient symbolically or rewrite this code as a function and make a standard +-eps calculation. If you need a gradient to run optimization (you code looks like a fitness function) you could use algorithms that calculate them themselves, for example, `fminsearch` can do this

Comment: you also get the position of the parentheses wrong... check the latex source, the image is misleading